# How update rows with reloadRowsAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, delete-row

I'm trying to delete cell with a Button.

Here is the implementation of a cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 30.f, 30.f);
        [btn addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(btnTouched:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [cell addSubview:btn];
      cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    }
   return cell;
}

- (void)btnTouched:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];

    [_myMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [_tableView endUpdates];
}
```

This works well until I've delete a row, the button isn't reloaded so after a delete, I don't delete the good index. I tried to put `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` for `visible indexPath` after the `endUpdates` method and it works very well. But the delete animation became ugly by the reloadRows animation (even if I set it to NO).
So is there a way to reload cells without reloadCellsAtIndexPath. Or delete a rows without using tags.

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to lookup the index of the cell by using logic similar to the following:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[sender superview]];
```

With this approach, you would not need to store the value of the row index in the cell tag.

Answer (score 0):

To just reload the table (and thus all its cells), you could try just using:

```
[_tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I've also try it and it works very well. But the animation of deleting is not the same. Try with and without, you can see a difference between both...