# Button image does not change after reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have `UIButton` in `UITableViewCell` which calls following selector :

```
-(void)geolocation:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = sender;
    if([[[btn imageView]image] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_gray_big.png"]])
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"geotag_big.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_gray_big.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

This works perfectly fine until `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is called on one of the swipe button. This is what I am doing on swipe button event :

```
[tableViewTasks beginUpdates];
                                 commentsView.hidden = YES;
                                 [dict setObject:@"yes" forKey:@"comment"];
                                 [arrTasks replaceObjectAtIndex:[[tableViewTasks indexPathForCell:cell] row] withObject:dict];
                                 [commentsView removeFromSuperview];
                                 [tableViewTasks reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[tableViewTasks indexPathForCell:cell], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                                 [tableViewTasks endUpdates];
```

After updating the cell, the button doesn't change the image, although conditions are correctly executed.
What might be the reason ? I went through [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802490/after-reloadrowsatindexpaths-custom-uitableviewcell-appearance-doesnt-change) but it didn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How update rows with reloadRowsAtIndexPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995166/how-update-rows-with-reloadrowsatindexpath)

Comment: So this swipe button is different from the button which is calling `geolocation:` method, right?

Comment: @Gandalf : Yes. geoLocation button is on the cell and swipe button comes on swipe only.